# Unable to use NPM due to network proxy

Tags: npm, npm-install

I have installed Nodejs on my VM & when I run command npm create-react-app myapp then I get

```
npm ERR! code ECONNRESET
npm ERR! errno ECONNRESET
npm ERR! network request to http://registry.npmjs.org/create-react-app failed, reason: read ECONNRESET
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'
```

Is there any way I can skip the network proxy and be able to use npm to create boiler plate code for React.

Comment: Are you at work, at home or at a Cloud service?

Comment: @lucasgcb I am at work

Comment: Are you able to open `http://registry.npmjs.org/create-react-app` from browser?

Comment: @tarzenchugh When I hit that URL then only in firefox I am able to get JSON of it in all other browers the link is not working

Comment: can you try this command `npm config set registry "http://registry.npmjs.org/"` or `npm config set proxy http://network_proxy_host:port`

Comment: @tarzenchugh I've tried doing this but no luck. Can you please help me with the links that I can request my network team to open for me on VM so that I can proceed with npm create-react-app myapp. Also suggest if there is any additional URL that needs to be opened for seamless usage of React application. Please note that in my VM there is no internet access everything is blocked by Firewall proxy I would have to get URLs in whitelist to access them. Will whitelisting this URL will serve the purpose - "http://registry.npmjs.org/" or if there is any other URL let me know.